# How can I scroll in the GRUB 2 shell?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, grub2

The outputs of the [help](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/help.html#help) and/or `vbeinfo` command of the [GRUB 2](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/) shell are massive. How can I scroll up the output? I've tried <kbd>PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd>, but nothing happened.

[image: Massive output in the GRUB 2 shell. How can I scroll?]

Comment: I don't know the "proper" way to do it, but if you launch the grub-shell within screen, you can use its scrollback feature to get at the overflowed lists.

Comment: @Xyon, what **scrollback** feature? do you mean the kernel parameter mentioned in [this thread](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-728450-highlight-grub2.html)?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

After googling, I still haven’t found a way to scroll up the output of the GRUB 2 shell. However, there's a way to pause output (like the behaviour of the *[more](https://linux.die.net/man/1/more)* command) - the `pager` environment variable.

> **13.1.24 pager**
>
> If set to ‘1’, pause output after each screenful and wait for keyboard input. The default is not to pause output.

So, issue a `set pager=1` command first in the GRUB 2 shell, and then the output will behave like *more*.

[image: GRUB 2 shell: set pager=1, and the output will be paused after each screenful]

**References**

- *[15.1.35 pager](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/pager.html#pager)* (GRUB manual)
- *[Pager support](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB2#Pager_support)* ([Arch Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux) wiki)

Comment: You just rescued my broken GRUB.

Comment: The *www.linuxmanpages.com* link is broken (times out). [A candidate](https://linux.die.net/man/1/more) for replacement.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Broken link is fixed, thanks for the information.